# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.companyname.cine.domain.Peli.actores, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Estoy comenzando con Spring y me he encontrado con este error tan habitual. Tras leer mucho y probar muchas de las soluciones sugeridas (bucles for para inicializar, uso de transactional etc) en StackOverflow y otros sitios he sido incapaz de arreglarlo.

Los objetos involucrados son un objeto Actor que tiene una relación @manytomany con un objeto Peli (tabla intermedia id_actor/id_peli). Además hay una relacion @onetomany entre Peli y Genero (id_genero en la tabla pelis).

La pantalla en cuestión es un formulario donde se trata de cargar una lista con todos los actores.

He aquí el código relevante:

### Actor.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "actores")
public class Actor implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String biografia;
    private List<Peli> pelis; 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

//otros setters y getters

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actores")
    public List<Peli> getPelis() {
        return pelis;
    }
}
```

### Peli.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pelis")
public class Peli implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String titulo;
    private String argumento;
    private Integer id_genero;
    private List<Actor> actores;

    public Peli(String titulo, String argumento, Integer id_genero) {
        //constructor
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //otros setters y getters, hashcode, equals, toString etc

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "actores_pelis", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_actor", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_peli", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public List<Actor> getActores() {
        return actores;
    }
}
```

### ActorDaoImpl.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.repository;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.companyname.cine.domain.*;

@Repository
public class ActorDaoImpl implements ActorDao {

    private EntityManager em = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<Actor> findByPeli(int id_peli) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Actor> actores = em.createQuery("select distinct a from Peli p join p.actores a where p.id=:id")
            .setParameter("id", id_peli).getResultList();
        //intento de inicializar la coleccion       
        for (Actor actor : actores) {       
            for (Peli peli : actor.getPelis()) {
                peli.getId();
            }
        }
        return actores;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional //<- intento de mantener la sesion abierta para no perder el acceso al objeto
    public List<Actor> findAll() {
        List<Actor> actores = em.createQuery("select a from Actor a order by a.id").getResultList();
        //intento de inicializar la coleccion   
        for (Actor actor : actores) {
            for (Peli peli : actor.getPelis()) {
                peli.getId();
            }
        }
        return actores;
    }

//otros métodos (save, update, delete, findById, etc etc

    }
}
```

### PeliDaoImpl.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.repository;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.companyname.cine.domain.*;

@Repository
public class PeliDaoImpl implements PeliDao {
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Peli> findAll() {
        List<Peli> pelis = em.createQuery("select p from Peli p order by p.id").getResultList();
        for (Peli peli : pelis) {
            for (Actor actor : peli.getActores()) {
                actor.getId();
            }
        }
        return pelis;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Peli findById(int id) {
        return em.find(Peli.class, id);
    }
//métodos save, update, delete
}
```

### ActorServiceImpl.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.companyname.cine.domain.Actor;
import com.companyname.cine.repository.ActorDao;

@Service("actorService")
public class ActorServiceImpl implements ActorService {

    ActorDao actorDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setActorDao(ActorDao actorDao) {
        this.actorDao = actorDao;
    }

    public Actor findById(int id) {
        return actorDao.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Actor> findByPeli(int id){
            List<Actor> actores = actorDao.findByPeli(id);
        return actores;
    }

    public List<Actor> findAll() {
            List<Actor> resultado = actorDao.findAll();         
        return resultado;
    }

//metodos save, update, delete
}
```

### PeliServiceImpl.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.companyname.cine.domain.Peli;
import com.companyname.cine.repository.PeliDao;

@Service("peliService")
public class PeliServiceImpl implements PeliService {

    PeliDao peliDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setPeliDao(PeliDao peliDao) {
        this.peliDao = peliDao;
    }

    public Peli findById(int id) {
        return peliDao.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Peli> findAll() {
        return peliDao.findAll();
    }

//metodos save, update, delete

}
```

### PeliController.java

```
package com.companyname.cine.web;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.*;


import com.companyname.cine.domain.*;
import com.companyname.cine.service.*;

@Controller("/peli")
public class PeliController {

    @Autowired
    private PeliService peliService;

    @Autowired
    private GeneroService generoService;

    @Autowired
    private ActorService actorService;

    // Este es el método donde se produce el problema
    @RequestMapping(value = "/peli/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional
    public String showUpdatePeliForm(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {

        Peli peli = peliService.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("peliform", peli);
        model.addAttribute("listaGeneros", generoService.findAll());

        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        //lo pongo así para facilitar el debug, pero el problema es al renderizar listaActores en la template
        List <Actor> listaActores = actorService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listaActores",listaActores);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        List <Actor> listaActoresEnPeli = actorService.findByPeli(id);
        model.addAttribute("listaActoresEnPeli", listaActoresEnPeli);

        return "pelis/peliform";
    }   

  //metodos de save, delete y update, mostrar formulario de alta, etc

}
```

### Template pelis/peliform resumida

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
<title><fmt:message key="title" /></title>
<style>
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <fmt:message key="editpeli.heading" />
    </h1>
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="peliform"
        action="/cine/pelis.htm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Seleccionar más actores: <form:select multiple="true" path="actores">                       
                        <form:options items="${listaActores}" itemLabel="nombre"
                            itemValue="id"></form:options>
                    </form:select></td>
            </tr> 

        </table>
        <br>
        <form:hidden path="id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Execute">
    </form:form>
    <a href="<c:url value="../../pelis.htm"/>">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### Application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">


    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity / -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cinePU"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:database="${jpa.database}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as 
        beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.cine.repository,com.companyname.cine.service, com.companyname.cine.validator" />


</beans>
```

A ver si alguien puede orientarme un poco para decirme en qué me estoy equivocando o qué estoy olvidando.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por favor no "descargues" todo tu programa para que alguien te lo depure por tí. Encuentra dónde está el fallo, haz [un ejemplo mínimo que lo reproduzca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), y si sigues teniendo el problema (muchas veces el fallo aparece simplemente con buscarlo), pon aquí el ejemplo mínimo, indicando qué fallo te da (lo has hecho) y en que parte del código sucede.

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que estás intentando obtener los datos del proxy pero la sesión (el `EntityManager`) está cerrado. Esto suele suceder cuando el método sale de la parte transaccional. Mis recomendaciones: 1) mover el `@Transactional` a un nivel/capa superior donde te permita obtener los datos que necesitas de las relaciones iniciadas mediante proxy, ó 2) no usar proxy porque realmente necesitas obtener los datos cuando se ejecuten los queries para traer la data.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Luiggi Mendoza, moviendo el `@transactional` debería funcionar.

En mis proyectos esta anotación la pongo encima del @Services en las clases servicios en tu caso quedaría de esta manera:

```
 package com.companyname.cine.service;

    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import com.companyname.cine.domain.Actor;
    import com.companyname.cine.repository.ActorDao;
    @Transactional
    @Service("actorService")
    public class ActorServiceImpl implements ActorService {

        ActorDao actorDao;
    ...
```

En vez de ponerla sobre los metodos de repositorios.
Esto se debe a que las colecciones se cargan de modo lazy. Otra opcion es poner el FetchType.Eager en la clase dominio, en el manyToMany:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```